# Pulseaudio issues - line out/headphones defaulting; connection to other programs ("not running as session daemon")

Tags: arch-linux, pulseaudio

I am running Pulseaudio with a combined digital+analogue channel (the digital is an HDMI connection to my monitor('s speaker); the analogue is a connection to separate speakers).

Whenever the pulseaudio daemon starts it seems to default to "Headphones" rather than "Line out" (both report as "unplugged" even though the line out is, in fact, plugged in). Is there a way to set the default to "Line out" rather than "Headphones"?

A separate (though potentially related) issue is that when monitor has gone to sleep and been re-awaked Pulseaudio apparently is no longer running as a session daemon - as when I try to connect with `pulseaudio-ctl` it can't find the connection, reporting "No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon."  I have to kill the daemon, and then it will restart in a way that `pulseaudio-ctl` can access it.